# Google play billing library: manage purchases on a custom database

Tags: android, play-billing-library

When we integrate google play billing library in our app, it is pretty clear that google play will manage the purchases on their servers.

This means that we are able to read what each user paid from the server of google play.

Now what if I want to use the google play billing library for receiving payments, but I manage the payments and track users on my custom server or any other database like (Firebase).

Then can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not. Just always consume (for inapp) or acknowledge (for subs) the purchase since you're tracking it by yourself.